# Black grub with purple border

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 I can't get into my Windows 7 partition.  The grub screen appears black with a purple border but I cannot choose anything.

If I try a `sudo update-grub` then I get a working grub screen but if I run Ubuntu I get kernel panics.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this one? Running into the same problem...

Comment: Have a look at this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1289809

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar symptoms. All this happened after upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04. No explanation - pure voodoo.

Grub loads the selection screen. For me Ubuntu boots perfectly. Choosing Windows leaves the screen either purple or purple with black spots. And stays like that. Numlock works, ctrl-alt-del works.

I exercised several different combinations with boot-repair. Restoring MBR instead of grub lead to straight boot into windows as expected. Any other configuration - installing grub in MBR or on linux partition - returned the situation as described in the beginning.

After a desperate attempt of checking keystrokes, I managed to discover an unexplainable (for me) but stably working procedure - when the blank purple screen is reached after choosing windows at grub menu, I hit 'y' - seems to me that it could stand for 'yes' but then it promptly proceeds into windows. Like Magic.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, immediately after posting the above, I found the culprit...

Removing the following line from grub.cfg:

```
parttool ${root} hidden-
```

allows me to boot into Windows without pressing any key, just as before upgrading.

Comment: And I finally figured out the actual source of the problem: boot-sector virus protection was turned on in the BIOS settings of my machine.  Apparently it doesn't like parttool setting the "hidden" flag on the partition, and prompts a "Continue (y/n) ?" prompt that is, for some reason, invisible at boot time in Grub.  So either edit the grub.cfg file, or turn off boot-sector virus protection in your BIOS.